# Delete user completely

Tags: php, delete-row, sql-delete

If a user or an admin wanted to delete a user completely from the site. how would you go about setting a query to remove that user from every table/subtables where the users id is contained. Here is the list of my tables with the subtables where the possible id of an individual user could be.

1. user
2. albums - user_id
3. block - user1_id
4. blogdata_comments - comment_poster
5. blogdata_feedback - feedback_userid
6. friends - user1_id or user2_id
7. messages - message_creator OR message_target
8. notifications - notification_targetuser OR notification_triggeredby
9. photo_comments - photo_comment_poster
10. streamdata - streamitem_creator OR streamitem_target
11. streamdata_comments - comment_poster
12. streamdata_feedback - feedback_userid
13. userphotos - photo_ownerid

Comment: If you have foreign key constraints, then you can use DELETE CASCADE, otherwise you'll probably need to delete from each table in turn

Comment: You could use an ORM, like Doctrine, which probably makes life 100x easier in situations like this.

Comment: can I set a foreign key up on each table? and do I set it to each subtable that contains the users specific id?

Comment: @bali182 that would be complete unlike "correct"

Comment: Something like this?


`ALTER albums
ADD CONSTRAINT user1_id
FOREIGN KEY foreign_key_name(user_id)
REFERENCES parent_table(user)
ON DELETE action
ON UPDATE action`

Comment: Set up a stored procedure that handles everything that you need to do for the deletion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Dave i could be way off the mark with this but i think you could do something like this which would also stop the user from creating a new account.

You would obviously need to make your own version of the very basic code below but it should work?

**EDIT**
just thought ud need their ip already

```
$db = new mysqli ('host', 'username', 'password', 'database');

$removeUser = "DELETE FROM (user, albums, block, and-so-on) WHERE `user-id`='$user'";

if(removeUser = $db->query($removeUser)){
    $ipAddr = $_SESSION['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $banList = "INSERT INTO banned (ipAddr) VALUES ('$ipAddr')"

        die($user . 'removed from all tables');

    if($banList = $db->query($banList)){
        die($user . 'Added to banned list');
    }else{
        die('Error adding ' . $user . ' to banned list');
    }
}else{
    die ('Unable to remove user from all tables');
}
```

Comment: Wow. That is a very nice feature I didn't even think about. Thanks for that Parody.

Comment: Sidenote: `user-id` in `WHERE user-id='$user'` would either need to be wrapped in backticks `\`` or use an underscore instead `WHERE user_id='$user'` - SQL will interpret it as being a mathematical problem **(minus)**. Just a quick "FYI" ;) Plus, a few missing semi-colons.

Comment: I made the edits to clean it up for other people that may read this, i know it was rough around the edges for sure but was trying to point him in the right direction rather than write code he could just copy and paste over :)

Comment: I wasn't criticizing it ;) just saying in case someone visited the question. Good work +1